# 40tb storage on sles 11 sp1

Tags: xfs, sles11

I managed to set /dev/sdb to gpt, mkfs.xfs then mount it. But whenever I rsycnc file, it will shows kernel error related to xfs in log messages and failed at about 5GB to 6GB total size rsync.

I read that if I want to use ext4, I need to recompile e2fsprogs to => 1.4.3 (current 1.4.1) with 64 bit options.

What are my options? I'm thinking of sharing that 40tb storage from another server as NFS to this SLES 11 server.

error:
filesystem "sdb": XFS internal error xfs_alloc_read_agf at line 2293 of file /usr/src/BUILD/kernel-default-2.6.32.12/linux-2.6.32/fs/xfs/xfs_alloc.c. Caller 0xffffffffa0324780

Comment: What are those error messages?

Comment: question updated with error

Comment: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3594951 : Seems there's a kernel 2.6.32.59 available in SP1 matching yours. If there's a bug in the kernel, best thing is to upgrade it (there's also a newer (3.0) in SP4)

Comment: too bad I can't upgrade since there's no more support contract with suse many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest SLES and open a support case.

If you will not get support, migrate the services on this host to an operating system that does not need paid support.